# Determining when an IE window is displaying a dialog box from a desktop app

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer-7, ui-automation, mshtml, shdocvw

I am attempting to determine if a selected browser window is showing a dialog box. I am using the shdocvw.internetexplorer object to grab the browser and get specific elements of the browser. I am unable to determine if a dialog box is showing.

I've also looked at using System.Windows.Automation but can't figure out how to get the tree setup in VB and then to look for the dialog box